# Search Column with Like by Lookup table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a "Description" field.  Which contains the titles of a whole lot of phone models.

```
**Table1**
Id - Int (PK)
Description - nvarchar(200)

**Lookup Table**
LookupId - Int (PK)
SearchString - nvarchar(50)
Result - nvarchar(100)
```

I then have another lookup table with all the different models of phones I want to search for.

If I was going to do a text search on the description field I could easily write this by doing

```
SELECT * FROM Listing WHERE Description Like '%SearchTerm%'
```

However I want to somehow do a search on each record in the Lookup Table.  Im thinking that I probably have to do a loop for each record in the Lookup table and then write some dynamic sql?  Is there an easier way than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you basically want to join your [Table1] to [Lookup Table] whenever [Table1].[Description] is like [Lookup Table].[SearchString].

You can try this:

```
select * from Table1 
join [Lookup Table] 
on Table1.Description like ('%' + [Lookup Table].SearchString + '%');
```

This will only return records where there is a match on the `like` condition. You can adapt this to an outer join if you need *all* rows from one of the tables, as required.

I won't vouch for the performance of this query. Also, it is an adaptation of [another question on Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276344/like-operator-in-inner-join-in-sql).

Comment: Thank you for this!  Its a one of process so not concerned with the performance :)